# If a composition function is one-to-one, does that imply its component is also one-to-one?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

If you know that `f(g(x))` AND `f(x)` are one-to-one/injective, then does that mean that `g(x)` is one-to-one/injective? Why or why not?

Thanks guys.

Comment: If $g$ and $f \circ g$ are defined on $D$, then yes. Otherwise we have, for some $x,y$ in $D$ such that $x \neq y$, $g(x) = g(y)$. Considering $f(g(x))$ and $f(g(y))$, what contradiction can we derive?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined on D"?

Comment: See the [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), under "other properties".

Comment: $g(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam so that's a reasonable counterexample to prove that g(x) is not injective?

Comment: @Thandor7765 Yes.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how that one example generalizes for every possible case. How is one example enough to conclude that: g(x) is not injective?